# SQL in Oracle Group by NULL returns multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by, crosstab

I have a sql statement which is trying to retrieve the rows having a count greater than 1 for all the similar rows. In all those rows, one field appears to be holding null value.

Case 1 :

Let's say the table name is ABC

---

BUSINESS_UNIT,    INVOICE,        FLAG

A                  1          (Null)

A                  1          (Null)

---

SQL Statement :  SELECT BUSINESS_UNIT, INVOICE, FLAG from TABLE ABC group by BUSINESS_UNIT, INVOICE, FLAG having COUNT(*) > 1

I am expecting it to return no rows as both the flags are basically blank. But it returns the

---

BUSINESS_UNIT, INVOICE, FLAG

A             1     (Null)

---

Case 2 :

TABLE ABC

---

BUSINESS_UNIT, INVOICE,    FLAG

A           1          (Null)

A           1          (Null)

B           1            1

B           1          (Null)

---

SQL Statement : SELECT BUSINESS_UNIT, INVOICE, FLAG from TABLE ABC group by BUSINESS_UNIT, INVOICE, FLAG having COUNT(*) >1

I am expecting the result to be

---

BUSINESS_UNIT, INVOICE, FLAG

B            1         1

---

This is for Oracle 11g. Can someone please help on this and let me know if we can use any of the delivered functions in Oracle?

---

After editing the original sql statements.

I should actually have removed flag from the Group by and select and added to the count in order to identify multiple flags for similar rows.

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found what I was intending to look for.

SELECT BUSINESS_UNIT, INVOICE 
from TABLE ABC 
group by BUSINESS_UNIT, INVOICE
having COUNT(DISTINCT Flag) >1

Case 1:  It returns no rows

Case 2 : It returns 1 row

---

BUSINESS_UNIT, INVOICE

B                1

---

Thanks Raphael, Dnoeth and Gordon for your help on this!

Answer (score 3):

well, null is also a value, so if you group by a nullable field, null values will be distinct from non null values.

If you don't wanna null values, just add a where clause

```
SELECT INVOICE 
from TABLE ABC 
where flag is not null
group by BUSINESS_UNIT, INVOICE, FLAG 
having COUNT(*) >1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Raphael, the filter will work in Case 1, but for Case 2 it won't work as expected.

Comment: @startedFromTheBottom there's nothing which could make your second query work... `1 <> NULL`

Comment: @startedFromTheBottom except if flag can only be 1 or null. Is it like that, or not ?

Comment: Raphaël : Flag can only only be 1, 2 or null. Now I am thinking that I should not put flag in the group and somehow count the number of distinct flags that I have and while counting the flags, use ( NVL to get null as some random ) . What do you suggest?

Comment: @startedFromTheBottom Hmmm, I'm stuck here : if you have `B, 1, 1`, `B, 1, null`, `B, 1, 2`, what do you wanna retrieve ?

Comment: Raphaël : Let's simplify this. If we need to retrieve the result from the rows that you gave, we should be getting B, 1. We are basically indentify the distinct flags, if exists, for similar rows.

Answer (score 2):

This is your first query:

```
SELECT BUSINESS_UNIT, INVOICE, FLAG
from TABLE ABC
group by BUSINESS_UNIT, INVOICE, FLAG
having COUNT(*) > 1;
```

The `count(*)` is returning the number of rows in each group.  One of the groups is `flag` and the `NULL` values are all grouped together.  If you want to count non-NULL values of `flag`, then you can use:

```
SELECT BUSINESS_UNIT, INVOICE, FLAG
from TABLE ABC
group by BUSINESS_UNIT, INVOICE, FLAG
having COUNT(flag) > 1;
```

Or filter as Raphaël Althaus suggests.

Your second query is:

```
SELECT INVOICE
from TABLE ABC
group by BUSINESS_UNIT, INVOICE, FLAG
having COUNT(*) > 1;
```

You seem to magically want three columns in the output when there is only one column in the `select`.  Yes, you can have more columns in the `group by` than in the `select`, if you really want.

Your final question is:

> Can someone please help on this and let me know if we can use any of
>   the delivered functions in Oracle?

Of course you can.  Oracle has a very powerful set of functions.  Most of them are consistent with the ANSI standard and behave the same way on Oracle and on other databases.  You just need to learn how to use them correctly.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus . . . My keyboard doesn't have those funny characters ;)  Fortunately, cut-and-paste works.  Cheers.

Comment: Oh, I was not asking for ë, just ph ;) Anyway, just kidding !

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gordon, I am trying to identify the number of rows which are grouped by the same fields (Business Unit and Invoice )  but has different flag on these rows and the flag is null. I have updated the number of fields on the sql statement for Case 2. I think I have made a mistake of adding the flag in the group by.

Answer (score 0):

Besides adding a WHERE-clause as suggested by Raphaël Althaus you might also change count(*) to count(flag):

```
SELECT INVOICE 
from TABLE ABC 
group by BUSINESS_UNIT, INVOICE, FLAG 
having COUNT(flag) >1
```

Comment: Hi dnoeth, Thanks for the reply, I think I shouldn't have added the FLAG in the group. We can remove the FLAG from the group and use COUNT(flag) > 1.  Again, if there are two null for similar rows, it will retrieve the row which I would not expect.